# OpenCV 2.2 VS2010 - Get an "Access violation reading" in a very simple code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I just installed OpenCV 2.2 and Visual C++ 2010 and configured it.
I don't get compilation errors but running this code I get this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6c2f22f2 (msvcr100.dll) in Es_CornerDetector.exe: 0xC0000005: access violation reading location 0x002a1000.
```

Code:

```
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector;
    detector.create("SURF");
}
```

I really don't understand which can be the cause..

## Update:

The use of "detector.create()" may be wrong so I tried something different but i get another error (always when I try to access "detector"):

```
First-chance exception at 0x67608ef4 in Es_CornerDetector.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x02655008.
Unhandled exception at 0x67608ef4 in Es_CornerDetector.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x02655008.
```

Alternative code:

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    IplImage* img_temp = cvLoadImage("img.jpg");
    cv::Mat img(img_temp);
    if(img.empty()==1)
    {
            std::cout << "Can't load the image.." << endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector;
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector.detect(img,keypoints);
    return 0;
}
```

## Update 2

I get the same error in 2 different system both with VS2010 and VS2008 and also if I try to run the example code descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp that can be found in ..\OpenCV2.2\samples\cpp\descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp

## OpenCV 2.3.1 attempt (both binaries and compiled):

Wow, new exotic error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'keypoints' was corrupted.
```

I'm about to give up...

Comment: Can you point to a link that shows .create in usage? I don't see it in the API docs.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the use is wrong (http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#cv-featuredetector-create).. I think the correct use should be this:
        
        cv::FeatureDetector* detector;
 detector->create("SURF");
but I get the same error

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and figured out that the directory having opencv binaries in my system path was incorrectly led to wrong directory which contains vc10 or vc9 opencv binaries. See if your problem is something like this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need ensure that the following "Additional Dependencies" under the the Properties->Linker->Input are referring to the correct OpenCV libraries with debugger support.

i.e.

```
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_calib3d220d.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_core220d.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_features2d220d.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_highgui220d.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_imgproc220d.lib
```

instead of

```
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_calib3d220.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_core220.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_features2d220.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_highgui220.lib
C:\OpenCV2.2\lib\opencv_imgproc220.lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the OpenCV 2.3.1 superpack [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/). If that is still giving you trouble, I would try compiling OpenCV from source using [CMake](http://cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html). Follow [this guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) to build OpenCV from source.

Aside from the obvious problem of the DLL not being in the same directory as the executable, this looks like it might be a mismatch between the compiled binary architecture (i.e., 32-bit/VS2005 vs. 64-bit/VS2010) and the one you are running.

Hope that is helpful!

**EDIT :**
Can you try compiling and running this code (this is working perfectly on my system)? Make sure you use the 2.3.1 version for this one.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread("yourimage.jpg", 0);

    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("FAST");

    vector<KeyPoint> points;
    detector->detect(image, points);

    Mat imageColor;
    cvtColor(image, imageColor, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    drawKeypoints(imageColor, points, imageColor, Scalar(255, 0, 0), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG);
    imshow("imageColor", imageColor);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Can you also post a link to the image you are trying to run feature detection on? Also, how are you creating your project in Visual Studio?

Comment: With OpenCV 2.3.1 I get a different (and mysterious at the same time) error (see above).
About the architecture I think is not related because I tested the same code both on a 32-bit VS10 and a 64-bit VS10.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use libraries with 'd' suffix such as "opencv_core244d.lib" for debug, and use normal libraries such as "opencv_core244.lib" for release. it just works.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include opencv_nonfreeXXXX.lib, same way included other libs (e.g. opencv_coreXXXXd) in the project dependencies settings. Then you MUST explicitly declare this line of code:

> initModule_nonfree();

in your source code before doing any operation with SURF or SIFT. They are not free anymore! Wasted about a day figuring this out.

The error message thrown gives you no idea that this is potentially the problem.

Comment: Oh my word.... after 2+ weeks of wrestling this issue, I can't tell or thank you enough for sharing this. This **totally** fixed my issue. In my case, however, I used `initModule_features2d()`. THANK YOU. +100 Why didn't OpenCV talk more about this function?

Comment: @OliverSpryn: I totally understand how you feel! :) I am glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

In VS look at t to see what dll for opencv are being loaded.  Ensure that the dll is the one that you expect.

Also you can use ProcMon which is part of the SysInternals suite to see what is being loaded.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but dll seem to be fine. There are 5 opencv dll loaded and a lot of other system libs. The only doubt is that in the 5 opencv dll output is "Binary was not built with debug information"
Could be related to the problem?

Comment: "Binary was not built with debug information" - this should be fine.  My hunch is similar to mevatron in I was thinking that there is a mismatch with the dll used, and the lib that was linked.  It would be a good idea to just build from source, verify that all dlls loaded and libs are from the same compile, and then this will eliminate this as a potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the use of MFC to be "MFC in a shared DLL" and it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you link the OpenCV libraries to the default Visual Studio configuration (**All configurations**) instead of a **Debug** and **Release** configuration separately.

To change configuration select:

1. Properties of the project -->  Configuration (Upper Left corner) --> Select **Debug**
2. Properties of the project --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies

Make sure that you link OpenCV debug libraries (see the final **d** like opencv_calib3d220**d**.lib):

```
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_calib3d220d.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_core220d.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_features2d220d.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_highgui220d.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_imgproc220d.lib
```

1. Properties of the project -->  Configuration (Upper Left corner) --> Select **Release**

   2. Properties of the project --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies

Make sure tahat you link OpenCV release libraries (without the final **d**):

```
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_calib3d220.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_core220.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_features2d220.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_highgui220.lib
C:\OpenCV_Path\lib\opencv_imgproc220.lib
```

Hope that is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the .dll and d.dll that you include are exactly the ones in your opencv forlder "d.dll" and ".dll", (for Release and Debug mode). Sometimes we follow a tutorial and don´t check that the names they give match with ours archives names. (They can be using other Opencv version and the names will change in something).